# Problema con Web Scraping Selenium en Python

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy tratando de hacer una simulación de nevagación, pero tengo un problema que no se como solucionarlo, ya que hago un cambio de web pero necesito elementos de la anterior. pasando en limpio, muestro el codigo para que sea entendible:

```
links = ['http://shop.sweetlady.com.ar/productos-en-underwear-6',
         'http://shop.sweetlady.com.ar/productos-en-sport-10']

items = []

for LINK in links:
    browser.get(LINK)

    productos = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("owl-stage-outer")
    for prod in productos:

        ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(prod).perform()
        #CLICK EN SHOPNOW
        boton = WebDriverWait(prod, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "shopnow")))
        browser.implicitly_wait(10)
        boton.click()

        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bread"]/div/ul/li[2]/a').click()
```

El problema surge cuando el `for` de `productos` se encuentra en la segunda vuelta, ya que en la lista `productos` el item `prod` no me lo toma y me arroja la `excepcion` :

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference:
>   element is not attached to the page document

Mi idea es `clickear` en el producto y luego volver a la página inicial, pero al volver a la página inicial tengo el problema con `prod` porque deja de existir en el DOM. Mi pregunta es si hay alguna solución para un problema asi?.

Comment: Cuando regresas a la pagina principal la lista de productos ya no es la misma, imaginate si agregaran un nuevo producto o eliminaran uno mientras estas viendo otro producto, lo que podrías hacer es despues de llenar "productos" en lugar de mantener una lista de los WebElements obtener el size de cuantos productos son y después tu for hacerlo de acuerdo al indice del producto.

Comment: efectivamente, lo resolví de esa manera, se me ha olvidado subir la respuesta, pero es como lo estás indicando, gracias.